# Azure DevOps Pipeline not update correct the website

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i build a pipeline, that should run on changes on master-branch. at the moment, it runs right, but the code is not changed. If i delete and recreate the pipeline, the update is correct installed. Where is my Error? The server is actually a F1 Plan from Azure (a linux maschine).

```
parameters:
- name: artifactName
  type: string
  default: drop

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.11.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.11.0
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-r linux-x64 --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: '...nameOfSubscription'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: '...nameOfWebApp'
    packageForLinux: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/*.zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|5.0'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply didn't deploy application to Azure. What you did is create a package for deployment.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: '$(Parameters.ArtifactName)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

It publishes artifact, but it doesn't publish your app to Azure.

Please take a look on documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows%2Cyaml#deploy-a-net-app)

If you want to do this in the same job it would be like:

```yaml
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<Azure service connection>'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    appName: '<Name of web app>'
    package: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/*.zip'
```

Please remeber to provide all needed details.